# NumberFormatException: For input string: "5,2"

Tags: android, numberformatexception

Please help me with this issue. I am adding code snippet and crash log here.

Code:

```
if (rssi <= -30 && rssi >= -90) {
    double len = ((rssi + 20) * -1) / 10.0;
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    float twoDigitsF = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(len));
    return String.valueOf(twoDigitsF);
}
```

I am getting the exception at the line

```
float twoDigitsF = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(len));
```

Here I am attaching my logs

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5,2"
       at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
       at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:424)
       at com.app.package.utils.Util.getRange(Util.java:26)
       at com.app.package.DriverActivity.scanDone(SampleActivity.java:982)
       at com.app.package.DriverActivity.access$1300(SampleActivity.java:126)
       at com.app.package.DriverActivity$11.onScanned(SampleActivity.java:913)
       at com.appchannel.bluetooth.BHelper$1.run(BHelper.java:67)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6317)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

**I got this log from Crashlytics. I am not able to reproduce this issue on my device.**

Comment: `5,2` does not conform to "a normal Java float". there may be a question about "localization" hiding here. Ideally the code would *not* use DecimalFormat as an intermediate step - use it to generate the *display*. Here it is used as an intermediate step only in which case the final result *might not only have two trailing digits anyway*.

Comment: ie: `return decimalFormat.format(len);` should be sufficient. (Note that this will return "5,2" or similar per the localization settings on the device.)

Comment: there is some issue with localization. I am passing the double value to the formatter,  how this double value changed to comma seperated string (5,2). If it is localisation isssue, how can i solve it?

Comment: I'd stop doing the needless step - and consider if the result *should* be localized at all :)

Comment: Thank you..  user2864740. I will change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what your locale is set to, the character between the integral part and the fractional part of the decimal number can be either `.`, `,`, or something else that I'm not aware of.

`DecimalFormat` automatically uses the character that corresponds to your locale, so that's why it formats to things like `5,2` instead of `5.2`.

However, `valueOf` does not take locales into account. It looks for `.` as the separator. So by putting 5,2`in there,`valueOf` can't recognise it.

To force the decimal format to format so that the result is compatible with `valueOf`, try to create the `DecimalFormat` with this:

```
new DecimalFormat("#.##", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
```

EDIT:

I saw that you convert the float back to a string again and return it. Why don't you just return the return value of `format`?

```
return decimalFormat.format(len);
```

Answer (score 0):

5,2is not double or float value ,so you should filter error value ! tosetting textview inputtype !

Answer (score 0):

no need to use decimal format.

```
yourfloat*=100f;
yourfloat = Math.round(yourfloat);
yourfloat =  yourfloat/100f;
```